# Sending form data to SharePoint list but nothing happens!

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, form, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-list

I am currently playing with a company SharePoint online with a view to make it look more "websitey".

I am having trouble sending the form information to a SharePoint list (called "Tasks". I am trying to create a new item.

Here is the list on SharePoint default view:
[image: Sharepoint Task List]

I am able to pull the list and put it on DataTable on the SharePoint site as shown below:
[image: DT sharpoint List]

I am using a Modal to make the form functional.

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalHorizontal">Add A Task</button>
```

×
                       Close
                
                
                    Add A Task

```
        <!-- Modal Body -->
        <div class="modal-body">

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form_id" method="post">



              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"
                      for="TasksForm" >Task</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea name="Task" id="TasksForm" style="height: 200px; width: 300px"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label"
                          for="EmployeeNameForm">Assign Task to:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                     <select name="Employees" class="form-control" id="employeeNameForm" style="width: 120px">
                          <option value="allstaff">All Staff</option>
                          <option value="a666">a</option>
                          <option value="b666">b</option>
                          <option value="c666">c</option>
                          <option value="d666">d</option>
                          <option value="e666">e</option>
                          <option value="f666">f</option>

                        </select> 
                </div>
              </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" 
                for="DueDateForm">Due Date</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY" type="text" style="width: 120px"/>
                    </div>
        </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

and the js I have for the submit button:

```
$("#submit").click(function addListItem(task, employeename, duedate, Tasks) {

var task = $('#TasksForm').val();
var employeename = $('#employeeNameForm').val();
var duedate = $('#date').val();
var listType = GetItemTypeForListName(Tasks);

function GetItemTypeForListName() {
    return "SP.Data." + Tasks[0].toUpperCase() + Tasks.substring(1) + "ListItem";
}
alert(listType);

// Prepping our update & building the data object.
// Template: "nameOfField" : "dataToPutInField"
var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": listType },
    "Task": task,
    "Title": employeename,
    "DueDate": duedate
}
$.ajax({

    url: "https://website.sharepoint.com/sites/development/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Tasks')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Success!");
        console.log(data); // Returns the newly created list item information
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("Error!");
        console.log(data);
    }
})

});
```

For the life of me, I really cannot figure out where I am going wrong. The page refreshes when I press "submit". no errors are shown. The in browser development console shows no errors loading the js on page.

Comment: What do you get in the Console.log? and can you try this instead: $("input[name='date']").val()

Comment: Your first screenshot is a "Modern Experiences" view. Microsoft has disabled all branding or custom JavaScript in Modern Experiences. Are you sure you are using Classic mode for your Form (not 100% sure, but I thought Modern and Classic couldn't mix)

Comment: @S Merchant: I cleared the cache (whoops) and now get "error!"
Also Tried $("input[name='date']").val() and it doesnt make a difference.

Comment: @365CSI: Thank you for the comment. I have looked into what you said and it seems to only apply if I am directly editing the list aspx. I am just calling from the list and posting to the list through REST. as I am able to GET with REST, I suspect I would also be able to POST? I am not 100% sure that the modern experience would affect that - what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I answered it and thought I'd post it for the record.

S Merchant pointed out a key fault - the date input. Thank you for that!

I changed the code as shown below:

```
$("#submit").click(function addListItem(task, employeename, duedate, listTitle) {

var listTitle = "Tasks"
var task = $('#TasksForm').val();
var employeename = $('#employeeNameForm').val();
var duedate = $("input[name='date']").val(); 
var listType = getItemTypeForListName(listTitle);


function getItemTypeForListName(listTitle) {
return"SP.Data." + listTitle.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + listTitle.slice(1) + "ListItem";
};

console.log(listType)

var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": listType },
    "Task": task,
    "Title": employeename,
    "DueDate": duedate
}
$.ajax({

    url: "https://keypharmaceuticals.sharepoint.com/sites/development/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Tasks')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: 
    console.log("Success!"),
    error: 
    console.log("Error!")

    })
});
```

A few things seemed to be causing stresses in the code:

- console.log(data) was not functioning. Got rid of it. God help us if we need to debug this in the future.
- "var duedate = $('#date').val();"  should have been: "var duedate = $("input[name='date']").val();"
- function getItemTypeForListName(listTitle) required new code and a new variable.
- I got rid of the alert for the listtype - that was mostly for my own reference.
- Also very minor mistake - caching was enabled and the js files were cached so changes I made in SPD would not update! Look out for that one!

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: `console.log()` didn't work?  Is this in IE? I know older versions of IE didn't create console until dev tools was open

Comment: console.log() works fine (it can post things on the log) but the console.log(data) was throwing a bit of a tantrum so I threw it out...

I did add maleman's error log feature and it works well so will be using that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are getting a posting error due to the Due Date field. SharePoint stores dates in the ISO format. Try something like this to convert your date before posting:

```
    if ($("#date").val()){
       inputDue = $("#date").val();
       dueDateTemp = new Date(inputDue);
       duedate = dueDateTemp.toISOString();
    }
```

In order to get more information in regards to the Ajax error, jQuery returns detail response information. You may access it in your error function like this:

```
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error){
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log("status="+ status);
        console.log("error=" + error)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you maleman for the tip - I added    
error: function(jqXHR, status, error){
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log("status="+ status);
        console.log("error=" + error)
    } 
and it works well. The information it throws at me in console is very useful.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `console.error()` for the error messages.  It simply makes it red, like it would other errors shown in console.